# Is it possible to encrypt portions of faces-config file?

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, security

I am working with JSF 2.1 Mojarra.  I have a Managed Bean that is initialized in the faces-config file.  There is some sensitive information in this file that I would like to encrypt.  Is this possible?  Or do I need to manage the object creation through some other mechanism.

Comment: What is the sensitive information? May you can just encrypt the value first and then put the encrypted one.

Comment: @BheshGurung, yes, it seems that I will have to decrypt the information once the object is created.  I guess I should have asked if there is a way to get JSF to do this on the fly.  It seems there is a mechanism to accomplish this with .NET.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would encrypt the data, then convert it to text either as hex or base64 encoding and put thr resulting string into you config - it just text so thee will be no problem.

Have the class that uses the data decode and decrypt the data before using it.

Comment: Good point.  I suppose I could use `@PostConstruct` to invoke a method that decrypts the information after the object is created. Does that sound reasonable to you?

Comment: Definitely. I didn't think of post construct, but that's quite clever!